# What is a good word for scheduled activities which are ready to be performed, and also those that aren't yet ready?

Tags: terminology

Let's say there's a number of scheduled activities. Some are due to be performed tomorrow, some next week, and some were even due yesterday but haven't been done yet.

Is there a good word to describe the division between items that are scheduled in the future vs scheduled now (also including the past)?

The best I've come up with is that the items that should be performed now are "due", while the others are "pending". But to me, "pending" somehow also signals something that is ready to be done (now!) but haven't yet been done, and that's the opposite of what I'm after. However, I'm not a native English speaker so I may be catching nuances in these words that aren't really there. Is there a better pair of words to describe "ready to be done" vs "scheduled for later"?

(BTW, this question comes from a software context, where activities are scheduled and triggered to be performed via timers, but I think the situation applies also to describe everyday things.)

Answer (score 1):

Adverbs before the word "scheduled" itself appear to always refer to the time the scheduling was or is to be done, as in *recently scheduled* or *soon-to-be-scheduled*. However,

1986, United States of America V. Guzzino - Page 29:
"Appellants to the contrary, the court fully allowed them to controvert the government's evidence linking the Pilotto shooting to the imminently scheduled starting date of the Arcado trial." In this case *imminently* appears to refer to the date's position in the schedule and not the time of scheduling.

You might consider *imminent, upcoming*, or *fast(er)-approaching* activities (or activities *at-hand*) as opposed to *more distant* or *non-imminent* activities on a schedule. Or perhaps *up-front* and *back* on the schedule (akin to the front of / the back of the queue in computer science as well as everyday usage).